# How to deselect View from multiple view When Select new one using gesture recognizer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

How to select a view from multiple view and previous selected will be deselect using TapgestureRecognizer ?

```
@objc func tapGestureHandler(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
    if drawView.isUserInteractionEnabled == true{
        return
    }
    if gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizer.State.ended{
        if let embedTextView = gesture.view as? EmbedTextView {
            textMode()
            self.textTools.editingTarget = embedTextView
        }
    }
    self.stampFrame.borderWidth = 1
    self.stampFrame.borderColor = UIColor.black


}
```

Comment: can you please add more detail. ?

Comment: Sure, I am selecting a  image from collectionView and add to them a view (stampView) .StampView is added to main view (self.view)  as subview .SO when i tap i get a stamp after this i want to select  one view (stampView) from this view and want o deselect previous selected on .

Answer (score 0):

To deselect within collection view:-

```
collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

// Get index from tap gesture
, for did deselect

```
@objc func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = sender.location(in: collectionView) // point of touch in collectionView
        if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location) { // indexPath of touch location
            let indexPaths = IndexPath(item: indexPath , section: 0)
            collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPaths, animated: true, scrollPosition: .top)
            collectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(collectionView, didDeselectItemAt: indexPaths)
    }
}
```

// Hope it works for you! thanks